# What does RHS of this code statement do?

Tags: android

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
```

It would be understandable for me if it was something like

```
ListView listView = new ListView()
```

But I don't understand what the RHS of ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview) means; I know that LHS creates a reference variable named listView which will contain the reference to an object of ListView.

To the best of my understanding, is it retrieving a view by findViewById() and parsing to a ListView object (how can an object of one type be even parsed into an object of another type) , and then assigning a reference to that ListView object in listView reference variable?
 Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's not parsing, it's casting.  And it's perfectly possible to cast one object to another, and to parse one object to another.  Consider `Integer.decode("3");`

Answer (score 1):

> R.id.listview

here in one of your xml layouts you name a list as "listview"

android assigns id to every name you allot. id are stored in R java file
it would be like

> public static final int listview=0x7f050002;

even you could directly use this int value in place of R.id.listview

> findViewById(R.id.listview);

this will tell your activity to find a view (whose id is stored as R.id.listview)

> (listview)

you are casting your view as a LISTVIEW object

and assigning it to the

> listView

object of class ListView